# Incompatible return type of phone number

Tags: java, regex, return, substring

How should i change code inside of getPhoneNumber to work correctly, any idea?
This is what i should get in the end +38(050)123-45-67. 38 is code of country, this is phone number 501234567, but you have to put zero in the begin of number to get 10 numbers like here (>0<50)

```
public String getPhoneNumber()
        {
           return String.format("+%d(%2$s)%3$s-%4$s-%5$s", 38,
                    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(0, 3),
                    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(3, 6),
                    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(6, 8),
                    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(8));

        }
```

Complete code.

```
public class Solution {
    public static Map<String,String> countries = new HashMap<String,String>();

    public static class IncomeDataAdapter implements Customer, Contact, IncomeData
    {
        IncomeData incomeData;

        public IncomeDataAdapter(IncomeData incomeData)
        {
            countries.put("UA","Ukraine");
            countries.put("RU", "Russia");
            countries.put("CA", "Canada");
            this.incomeData = incomeData;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName()
        {
            return incomeData.getContactLastName()+ incomeData.getContactFirstName();
        }

        @Override
        public String getPhoneNumber()
        {
           return String.format("+%d(%2$s)%3$s-%4$s-%5$s", 38,
                    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(0, 3),
                    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(3, 6),
                    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(6, 8),
                    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(8));

        }




        @Override
        public String getCompanyName()
        {
            return incomeData.getCompany();
        }

        @Override
        public String getCountryName()
        {
            return countries.get(incomeData.getCountryCode());
        }

        @Override
        public String getContactFirstName()
        {
            return "Ivan";
        }

        public IncomeData getIncomeData()
        {
            return incomeData;
        }

        @Override
        public String getCountryCode()
        {
            return "UA";
        }



        @Override
        public String getCompany()
        {
            return "JavaRush Ltd.";
        }

        @Override
        public String getContactLastName()
        {
            return "Ivanov";
        }

        @Override
        public int getCountryPhoneCode()
        {
            return 38;
        }
    }

    public static interface IncomeData {
        String getCountryCode();        
        String getCompany();            
        String getContactFirstName();  
        String getContactLastName();    
        int getCountryPhoneCode();     
        void getPhoneNumber();          
    }

    public static interface Customer {
        String getCompanyName();        
        String getCountryName();       
    }

    public static interface Contact {
        String getName();               
        String getPhoneNumber();        
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is pretty confusing.  Did you consider factoring out all the duplication by declaring a variable?

Comment: Im just begining to learn how to use adapter

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, it occurs in  getPhoneNumber

Comment: There is no error. there is problem with method xDD, i dont know what should i do

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, "attempting to use incompatible type"

Answer (score 0):

Both your `IncomeData` and `Contact` interfaces have a `getPhoneNumber` method. One declares a return type of `void` while the other declares a return type of `String`.

You're trying to implement both these interfaces with your `IncomeDataAdapter` class. By declaring the overriden method was

```
@Override
public String getPhoneNumber()
{
```

It doesn't satisfy the contract of `IncomeData`. If you declared it as

```
@Override
public void getPhoneNumber()
{
```

it wouldn't satisfy the `Contact` interface. Basically, you can't have methods with the same definition (name and parameter list) with different return types.

Change your `IncomeData` interface to declare a `getPhoneNumber` method with a `String` return type.